# How can I use a projection instead of raw columns

Tags: projection, ml.net

I have a dataset with columns for

- number of items (an integer value)
- weight of the items (a fractional value)
- A product category
- A start time
- An end time

and from this dataset I want to train a data model that given a number of items, weight and category can predict a duration (end time - start time).

How can I transform or set my label column to the duration, so that I get an `EstimatorChain` that I can call `Fit` on with an `IDataView` that I've loaded from CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ML.NET CustomMapping functionality, to calculate the duration, and call that Label. 
[This contains an example of how to use it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.custommappingcatalog.custommapping?view=ml-dotnet)

```
Action<Data, Data> mapping =
            (input, output) => output.Label= input.End - Input.Start;
```

where Data would be your data model that contains a Label property, in addition to the other properties.